gitlab run pipeline shows 'No such file or directory' when going to '~/deployer/'
when I 'cd ~/deployer' in using gitlab run pipeline shows that there is 'no such file Directory'
stages:
    - build

pull-repository-job:
    stage: build
    tags:
        - ci
        - shell
    only:
        - master
    before_script:
        - cd ~/deployer/safety/httpdocs/
    script:
        - echo "Start Deploy"
        - echo "Finished Build and Deploy"

It shows this error:
Executing "step_script" stage of the job script
00:00
$ cd ~/deployer/safety/httpdocs/
bash: line 142: cd: /home/gitlab-runner/deployer/safety/httpdocs/: No such file or directory
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
00:01
ERROR: Job failed: exit status 1


There could be two possibilities - 1. deployer folder not created in the home directory 2. you have permission issue in runner machine. Please check if you have any of them
